# LINQ2SQL Association: What's the meaning of unique?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ2SQL designer is Visual Studio 2010.

I have an association between two entities.

This is a One to Many relationship.

If you open the properties window, there is a property named "Unique" at the bottom of the list.

I do not understand the purpose of this property.

It has two possible values : true or false

How a  One to Many association can be unique.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This means that the table containing the ForeignKey cannot contain one value more than once in any other row for that column (property).

Comment: Isn't this a One to One association then?